# Updating the current logged on user, HKEY_USERS hive registry, with system account

Tags: powershell, registry, sccm

This script makes changes to all users' profiles.

Here is the script:

```
# Get each user profile SID and Path to the profile
$UserProfiles = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*" |
                Where {$_.PSChildName -match "S-1-5-21-(\d+-?){4}$" } |
                Select-Object @{Name="SID"; Expression={$_.PSChildName}}, @{Name="UserHive";Expression={"$($_.ProfileImagePath)\NTuser.dat"}}

# Loop through each profile on the machine
foreach ($UserProfile in $UserProfiles) {
    # Load User ntuser.dat if it's not already loaded
    if (($ProfileWasLoaded = Test-Path Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($UserProfile.SID)) -eq $false) {
        Start-Process -FilePath "CMD.EXE" -ArgumentList "/C REG.EXE LOAD HKU\$($UserProfile.SID) $($UserProfile.UserHive)" -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden
    }
}

# Manipulate the registry
$key = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($UserProfile.SID)\Software\SomeArchaicSoftware\Configuration"

New-Item -Path $key -Force | Out-Null

New-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name "LoginURL" -Value "https://www.myCompany.local" -PropertyType String -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name "DisplayWelcome" -Value 0x00000001 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null

$key = "$key\UserInfo"

New-Item -Path $key -Force | Out-Null

New-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name "LoginName" -Value "$($ENV:USERDOMAIN)\$($ENV:USERNAME)" -PropertyType STRING -Force | Out-Null

# Unload NTuser.dat 
if ($ProfileWasLoaded -eq $false) {
    [GC]::Collect()

    Start-Sleep 1
    Start-Process -FilePath "CMD.EXE" -ArgumentList "/C REG.EXE UNLOAD HKU\$($UserProfile.SID)" -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden| Out-Null
}
```

I only need changes to the current logged on user HKEY_USERS hive.
Can anyone help me change the script so it's only the current logged in user who gets the changes?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a logon script for this kind of thing?

Comment: Right now, it must be used for a program that is installed via sccm

Comment: As this is done via sccm would it be allowed to just run the program in user context or has the program to be run with the system account (e.g. to change a key in the user context where the user has insufficient permissions?)

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the SID of a currently logged-in user via WMI. Check for the owner of a running `explorer.exe` process, then resolve the account name to its SID:

```
$user = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'").GetOwner()
$fltr = "Name='{0}' AND Domain='{1}'" -f $user.User, $user.Domain
$sid  = (Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter $fltr).SID
```

Still, I think a logon script would be a better place for changes to a user's registry settings.

Comment: I understand your point. But I install programs via sccm and once in a while, a reg key has to be added to the user who is logged on and it will be done with system acount from sccm. 
You can't run it in the user context its has to run with the system account. Otherwise the program will not be uninstalled correctly

How do you add a reg key to that user. Can you give me an exemple from you post? Thanks

Comment: @Joe Your code already filters HKEY_USERS for SIDs. The code in my answer shows how to get the SID of the currently logged-in user. Now combine the two.

Comment: The main problem with any method that is only run once is that it will never work for future users on the same computer. Are you aware of that? That is the reason why you would normally use something like a logon script or gpos. If it has to be sccm you would normally split your program into two one with system rights one with user rights to be deployed for all users that log on. You can only really skip these methods if you have an environment that guarantees that every computer has only one user...